# Unable to release my app on App Store because it has pages that require Location

Tags: ios, app-store

I'm making an application that is for a company partnered with the company I work for.

The app won't be available for public use, only certain users will be able to use it.

But even though Apple knows that, as I put those details in the `Review Notes`, they still complain that my app locks pages behind Location Permission, saying

> Your app uses location data for features that are not relevant to a user's location. Specifically, your app is not functional when Location Services are disabled.

I'm not sure what they mean "not relevant"? It's a map page that uses the users location to show the relevant surrounding map, and the user can only click to add pins in a certain radius around their current location. How is that "Not Relevant"?

The text in the permission both in the app and in the `Info.plist` explain why I need the location permission.

What do I need to do? I can't have the page NOT use location, that's what the whole point of that specific page.

Comment: Does the app have any functionality at all if the user denies location access?

Comment: @Paulw11 yes. There are `On-Site` visits which require a location, and `Off-Site` visits which don't even ask you for permission

Comment: And what does you app do/show if the user does decline permission?  Does the rest of the app remain functional?

Comment: @Paulw11 yes you can just back from that page and the app is still working. And it just shows "Location Permission Required"